# Какие технологии нужно использовать для создания аналога скайпа на Java?

Tags: java, клиент-сервер, skype, messenger

Изучаю java, есть идея написать аналог скайпа для локальной сети. Подскажите какие технологии нужно использовать для создания подобного? В упрощенной версии можно сделать только передачу данных и сообщений (без видеозвонка или голосового вызова), далее усложнять. Подскажите с чего начать весь процесс разработки?

Comment: Лет так через 10 практики а не изучения, вернитесь к подобному вопросу, имхо совет.

Comment: можно сделать реверс-инженеринг скайпа и посмотреть как там и что

Comment: Ну можно не совсем скайп, просто с авторизацией, обменом сообщений и данных(файлов) между пользователями через сервер, все для локальной сети. Что-то наподобие чата, только р2р.

Comment: Из знаний/технологий вам потребуется только понимание сетевых протоколов, работа с сокетами в Java и основы многопоточности.

Comment: @РенатСапегин вы меня извините, но это еще один велосипед

Comment: @РенатСапегин  да и не понятно зачем использовать в качестве инструмента Java, для решения именно этой задачи? (это оффтоп и просто попытка понять для чего). А примеры чатов с пересылкой файлов в сети уйма в том числе и на  java.  А по существу. Процесс разработки начните с проектирования, представьте взаимодействия пользователя и системы, и как ваша система будет передавать принимать пакеты, в каком виде вы буде слать пакеты, возможно вы будете их шифровать. советую в таком случае посмотреть на RAW_сокет. Определитесь с типом пакета (TCP/UDP).

Comment: Cпасибо за совет, да я понимаю, что это новый велосипед. Мне в любом случае только для обучения, в реальной жизни проект существовать не будет.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Для реализации клиент-серверных приложений Вам необходимо использовать сокеты.

В простом варианте - Java IO (`Socket`, `ServerSocket`).

В более сложном, но производительном (асинхронная модель) - Java NIO (лучше взять фреймворк Netty).

Но это не касается передачи аудио/видео потоков. Речь только о передаче данных и сообщений.